# How to create delete link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I create delete link_to in Rails app?

Votes controller

```
    class VotesController < ApplicationController

    def destroy
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @user.votes.pluck(:author_uid).delete(current_user.uid)
    end

end
```

Routes

```
votes_path      GET     /votes(.:format)             votes#index
                POST    /votes(.:format)             votes#create
new_vote_path   GET     /votes/new(.:format)         votes#new
edit_vote_path  GET     /votes/:id/edit(.:format)    votes#edit
vote_path       GET     /votes/:id(.:format)         votes#show
PATCH                   /votes/:id(.:format)         votes#update
PUT                     /votes/:id(.:format)         votes#update
DELETE                  /votes/:id(.:format)         votes#destroy
```

What should I write in link_to in view?

I tried

```
= link_to 'Delete vote', {controller: "votes", action: "destroy"}, method: "delete"
```

and

```
= link_to 'Delete vote', vote_path(vote), method: :delete
```

users/index.html.haml

```
- @vk.friends.get(uid: current_user.uid, fields: fields) do |friend|
  %td.span
    .centred
      .image
        .circled
          = image_tag friend.photo_medium
      %span= friend.uid
      %span= link_to "#{friend.first_name}  #{friend.last_name}", "http://vk.com/id#{friend.uid}", target: "_blank"
      %span= define_age(friend) == '' ? define_sex(friend) : define_sex(friend) + ', ' + define_age(friend)
      - if current_user.user_votes.pluck(:recipient_uid).include?(friend.uid)
        = link_to('Delete',{controller: :votes, id: vote.id, action: :destroy}, confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete ?", method:  :delete)
      - else
        = link_to 'Vote', {controller: "votes", action: "create", uid: friend.uid}, method: "post", confirm: "You sure", class: 'button medium pink'
```

Of course it's not working. I'm sure I should fix it with routes, but I don't know how.

Please comment, if you need more information.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe your second example should work. What do you get instead? What HTML does it produce, and what request happens when you click the link?

Comment: It throws an error: undefined local variable or method `vote' for #<#<Class:0x331ec48>:0x35c65b0>

Comment: Ah. Chances are you've misused `vote` when you mean `@vote`, or similar. Can you post the controller code which produces the view containing that `link_to`?

Comment: Also, your `destroy` method isn't going to work. You find the user with the id of the `vote` that the form was for; then you produce an array of that user's votes' `author_uid` fields; then you remove the current user's id from that array - not the database. You probably just want `Vote.destroy(params[:id])`

Comment: Updated vote_controller. Tell me if I didn't understand

Comment: That's not the action that produces the destroy link. Your link is in `users/index.html.haml`, so we need to see the `index` method on the `UsersController`.

Comment: There is only @users = User.all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second `link_to` is fine, syntactically. The problem is that `vote` isn't defined. Try the following in your view:

```
  %span= define_age(friend) == '' ? define_sex(friend) : define_sex(friend) + ', ' + define_age(friend)
  - vote = current_user.user_votes.find_by_recipient_uid(friend.uid).first
  - if vote
    = link_to('Delete', vote, confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete ?", method:  :delete)
  - else
    = link_to 'Vote', {controller: "votes", action: "create", uid: friend.uid}, method: "post", confirm: "You sure", class: 'button medium pink'
```

You will also need to sort out your destroy action as I've noted in the comments on your question; and your create action may be suspect in similar ways; I haven't studied it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
= link_to('Delete', vote_path(vote.id),:method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete?")  
OR       
= link_to('Delete',{controller: :votes, id: vote.id, action: :destroy}, confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete ?", method:  :delete)
```

Comment: NameError undefined local variable or method `vote' for #<#<Class:0x331ec48>:0x2fa98b8>